# Whats the best way to get total # of records in a mysql table with php?

Tags: php, mysql

Whats the most efficient way of selecting total number of records from a large table? Currently, Im simply doing

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table");
$total = mysql_num_rows($result)
```

I was told this was not very efficient or fast, if you have a lot of records in the table.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You were told correctly.  mysql can do this count for you which is much more efficient.

```
$result = mysql_query( "select count(id) as num_rows from table" );
$row = mysql_fetch_object( $result );
$total = $row->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use [SQL's built in COUNT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/counting-rows.html):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table");
```

Answer (score 4):

**MyISAM tables already store the row count**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

on a MyISAM table simply reads that value. It doesn't scan the table or the index(es). So, it's just as fast or faster than reading the value from a different table.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) this is most efficient if you're using a MyISAM table (which is the most usual type of tables used):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
```

Otherwise you should do as Wayne stated and be sure that the counted column is indexed.

Comment: Nice - I didn't know they optimized count(*) when there's no other columns selected.  Still, I like to be in the habit if performing counts on the relevant columns, which is usually the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Can I just add, that the most "efficient" way of getting the total number of records, particularly in a large table, is to save the total amount as a number in another table.
That way, you don't have to query the entire table everytime you want to get the total.

You will however, have to set up some code or Triggers in the database to increase or decrease that number when a row is added/deleted.

So its not the easiest way, but if your website grows, you should definitely consider doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I agree to use the built-in functions, I don't really see any performance difference between mysql_num_rows and count(id). For 25000 results, same performance (can say exact.) Just for the record.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_things from table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$num_results = $row["total_things"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a large table (>50 million rows) and it took a long time to count the primary key, so I use the following:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "database";
```

Replace database with the name of your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to note that `SHOW TABLE STATUS` returns a `Rows` column, though I can't speak to its efficiency. Some light Googling turns up reports of slowness in MySQL 4 over two years ago. Might make for interesting time trials.

Also note the [InnoDB caveat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-table-status.html) regarding inaccurate counts.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate function. Try the below SQL Command

```
$num= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table");
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query() is deprecated. Better use this:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM {table_name}");
$total = $result->num_rows;
```

Using PDO:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM {table_name}");
$total = $result->rowCount();
```

(where '$dbh' = handle of the db connected to)