# Quickest way to get total records from a mysql table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the current code I use to get the total number of photos in a DB, An estimated number would even be acceptable as the number of results is just used to determine which folder number I would like to upload into for folder balance of files.

I have a feeling there is a better way then I am using below?

```
$sql = 'SELECT auto_id FROM friend_user_photo';
$query = executeQuery($sql);
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

$rowcount returns number of record in the friend_user_photo table

UPDATE:

Isn't there a way to read information about a database. that might be quicker then using above method or COUNT?

Comment: changed tag from 'mys2ql' to 'mysql', on the assumption of typo =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use COUNT.

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friend_user_photo';
$query = executeQuery($sql);
```

This will return a single row containing the number of results. This is also a regular aggregate function so you can do joins, sub queries, conditions (WHERE), grouping and all that good stuff.

You can also treat this as just another field, so you can alias it and then use it in your joins and sub queries. You can also select additional data, for example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*), name FROM table GROUP BY name
```

This will return a distinct list of names, but will also contain the number of records that exist for each of those names.

**Edit for alternative to count()**

If you don't want to use COUNT(*) you can also use 'show table status'. For example:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'friend_user_photo'";
// Note, this LIKE is a regular LIKE, so wild cards can be used
```

This will return a row with various meta-data including Rows, but also including Key Length (in bytes) and Data Length (in bytes) as well as a lot of other data. This is also usually quite fast since it's just pulling meta-data as apposed to running an aggregate function like COUNT(*) (so long as the table isn't locked by another query that's currently running).

Comment: thanks, I just need the total nu8mber of records, no conditions in WHERE or anything, the total number does not even have to be accurate, it can be an estimate, I was thinking there might be a way to read the table information and get an estimate of rows faster maybe then doing a select query

Comment: thanks, so "show table status" is supposed to be faster then anything else right?

Comment: It should prove faster than anything else as it's just pulling the table's meta-data as apposed to running a logical query like a SELECT. If the table is already locked by a query then it will of course be slow though.

Comment: "SHOW TABLE STATUS" never gives teh exact total no of rows in a table, it always gives an estimated no of rows in a table, so always use mysql's internal COUNT(*) function

Answer (score 4):

SELECT COUNT(auto_id) FROM friend_user_photo

Would be more direct and you wouldn't have to use mysql_num_rows($query).  You would just check the value returned from $query.

EDIT: Since you updated that you would like another idea than COUNT.

If auto_id is simply an integer or long, etc... that started at 1 and increments by one then how about LIMIT:

```
SELECT auto_id FROM friend_user_photo LIMIT 0,1
```

I'm not sure if it's faster though...

EDIT #2:

According to these posts:

If you are using myisam then COUNT is the fastest:

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/184095 -

> select count(*) from table is the fastest for myisam because it caches 
>   row count. This will also include any rows that have null values.

[Whats the best way to get total # of records in a mysql table with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116824/whats-the-best-way-to-get-total-of-records-in-a-mysql-table-with-php)

Comment: It might be worth noting that depending on the engine being used, COUNT() might potentially be quite a bit slower: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/