# Mysql Counting rows in a table and returning an integer

Tags: php, mysql, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the best way to get total # of records in a mysql table with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116824/whats-the-best-way-to-get-total-of-records-in-a-mysql-table-with-php)

When i run :

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(col) FROM table");
```

I end up with something like this :

> (Resource) mysql result #4

How can i only get an integer that represent the number of row in my table so that later i can use it to make a simpel check such as : $result < 10.

Many Thanks

Comment: TABLE is a MySQL reserved word. Use backticks(`) to quote the name or rename this table.

Comment: @Devart considering the OP is also using `col` for the column name here, I would imagine that the use of these words is just for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options.

Get the result from the resource returned by the count query:

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(col) FROM table");
$count = mysql_result($resource,0);
```

Or, get the number of rows from the resource returned by the query (without count).

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM table WHERE col IS NOT NULL");
$count = mysql_num_rows($resource);
```

I would recommend that you use the first, the reason being is that it is unnecessary to extract all the data from the table when you only need the count.

*Note I've added `WHERE col IS NOT NULL` on the second one in order to recreate the effect of `count(col)` as opposed to `count(*)`, as it will only count the non-null values of `col`.*

Comment: Those might not act the same. `count(col)` will count only non-null values of `col`, while the second one will count the number of total rows.

Comment: @DorShemer this is true - updated to add `IS NOT NULL` on the end

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query` returns a mysql resource. To get the query output use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(col) FROM table");
if (!$result) {
    die('Error:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

See more examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

**EDIT**

By the way, this will only count the number of rows with a non-null value in `col`. To get the total number of rows in the table, use `count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1. SELECT COUNT(*)....
2. Do the normal query. And add this line after retrieving the resource.

   ```
   $num = mysql_num_rows($resource);
   ```